# Showing uniform convergence of series

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2j}{(x^2 + j^2)^2}$ converges uniformly.

Don't know how to do this problem since $x$ and $j$ are in the expression together. Is there a convergence test I can use?

Comment: Let $s_n$ denote the sequence of partial sums. Then, the sum converges uniformly iff $s_n(x)$ converges uniformly as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ok, but is there a convergence test I can use for the expression inside the sum?

Comment: Have you heard of Abel's Uniform Convergence Test?

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not something that was covered

Comment: See [Mathworld Wolfram on this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsUniformConvergenceTest.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will read about this, but is there another method, since I am not able  to use this in class?

Comment: I don't remember... Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{-2j}{(x^2+j^2)^2}\le\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{-2j}{j^4}=
-2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j^3}$$

Hence it can be majorized by the convergent series $-2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j^3}.$

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:** you can use the M-test

$$\frac{2j}{(x^2 + j^2)^2} \leq \frac{2j}{( j^2)^2}.$$